# Displaying a SpriteKit View (SKView) inside an NSView

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skview

I'm trying to display a Sprite Kit View inside my app's window (not taking up the full screen)
For that i used the SKView element available in the Xcode library
[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRllS.png)

Xcode allowed me to select a scene available in the project, i selected the scene, at that won't display

[Selected Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlCQ6.png)

I ended up making an @property with the scene linked in my Main ViewController and then loaded the scene from there and used the presentView function, but it will still not display
[ViewController.h/.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKclC.png)

I also made sure Core Animation Layer was enabled for my view but that did nothing too.
I'm sure i'm missing very important steps into making it work and display, but since i'm on it for hours and won't progress at all, i wanted to know if you guys could help me, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your skview is in your view controller heirarchy, and not just floating about?

Comment: Yep, it's in my [hierarchy](https://imgur.com/a/GzVqpFI)